# How to create a regex for a line of text

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex for dreamweaver to convert each line to a link

Can anyone assist? My regex is very weak.

```
doc1.pdf<br />
Adoc2l.pdf<br />
aend.pdf<br />
AFedfasd.pdf<br />
```

Output should be

```
<a href="doc1.pdf">doc1.pdf</a><br />
```

Comment: Please add more details - what do you want, what have you tried and so on...

Comment: Hm, does dreamweaver understand anything like xpath?

Answer (score 1):

Search string: `^(.+)(<br\s?\/>)$`

Replacement string: `<a href="$1">$1</a>$2`

Comment: The criteria you have here is that any text before a `<br>` should be linkified, but the criteria (inferring from OP's code) could also be more strictly any PDF filename that comes before a `<br>`. We can't be sure without OP replying and better specifying what s/he is looking for.